# How to use Lazy query with React-query?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-query

I am using React-query for my API calls. I am wondering if there is a way to call the query in a lazy way.

Meaning to call the query only when a query param changes.

This is what I currently have; I am using a hack with the `useEffect` where if `recipeName` changes, then run the `refetch` function.

```
export const searchRecipeByName = async (recipeName: string) => {
  return await api.get(
    `/recipes/complexSearch?apiKey=${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SPOONACULAR_API_KEY}&query=${recipeName}&addRecipeInformation=true&fillIngredients=true`
  );
};
```

```
  const [recipeName, setRecipeName] = useState("");

  const { data, refetch } = useQuery(
    "homePageSearchQuery",
    () => searchRecipeByName(recipeName),
    { enabled: false }
  );

// HACK
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!!recipeName) {
      refetch();
    }
  }, [recipeName]);

  const handleOnSearchSubmit = async (recipeSearch: RecipeSearch) => {
    setRecipeName(recipeSearch.search);
  };
```

Preferably, I would like to call the query in the `handleOnSearchSubmit` function.

I could create a custom `useLazyQuery` hook to handle this, but I'm wondering if React-query has a native way to handle this.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Preferably, I would like to call the query in the "handleOnSearchSubmit" function.

This is a quite imperative way of thinking about things, but react-query is more declarative. You don't specify: "when I click that button, I want to fetch", but you just say: "these are the inputs I require" and react-query will refetch whenever those inputs change.

So what you want to do is put the things that you need for your query to run *into* the query key, so that react-query

- caches it separately for every dependency
- you can disable it as long as dependencies are not ready

```
const [recipeName, setRecipeName] = React.useState('')
const { isLoading, data } = useQuery(
  ['homePageSearchQuery', recipeName],
  () => searchRecipeByName(recipeName),
  {
    enabled: !!recipeName
  }
])
```

then, all you need to do is call `setRecipeName` in `handleOnSearchSubmit`, and react-query will do the querying.

some more things that you might want to consider:

- if you want to avoid a hard loading state in between `recipeName` changes, set `keepPreviousData: true`
- the above code will run a query every time the `recipeName` changes. If that doesn't happen on a button click, but say whenever the user types something in an input field, you you want to debounce that. For those cases, consider something like [useDebounce](https://usehooks.com/useDebounce/):

```
const [recipeName, setRecipeName] = React.useState('')
const debouncedRecipeName = useDebounce(recipeName, 1000)
const { isLoading, data } = useQuery(
  ['homePageSearchQuery', debouncedRecipeName],
  () => searchRecipeByName(debouncedRecipeName),
  {
    enabled: !!debouncedRecipeName
  }
])
```

This will let you input data and show it in a text field, but only creates a new cache entry / fires a new request after 1 second of inactivity.

- if you want to have a button that submits the form, it's  best to "lift state up": Have a more global state that the query depends on, and some local state for the form. Once the user hits "submit", you save the user selection in the state that lives higher up, which will trigger a query. I like to use the url for this, and I have a complete [codesandbox example here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-query-url-filtering-h0ikw?file=/src/App.tsx). The actual form state is uncontrolled in that example, but you can also use state or a form lib for that

Comment: Thanks TKDodo for the extensive answer. It's a shame that React-query doesn't have a useLazyQuery natively like Apollo client. I will give this a shot

Comment: @TKDodo can you not disable the query initially then manually call refetch when needed?

Comment: sure, but then you opt out of all the smart refetches / invalidation that react-query provides. everything is "manual" at that point. see: https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/guides/disabling-queries

Answer (score 2):

You can use this Wrapper hook to make `useLazyQuery` in `react-query`

```
import { useCallback, useState } from 'react';
import {
  QueryFunction,
  QueryKey,
  useQuery,
  UseQueryOptions,
  UseQueryResult,
} from 'react-query';

type UseQueryParams = Parameters<typeof useQuery>;

export default function useLazyQuery<TData, TError>(
  key: UseQueryParams[0],
  fetchFn: QueryFunction<TData, QueryKey>,
  options?: Omit<UseQueryOptions<TData, TError, unknown, QueryKey>, 'queryKey' | 'queryFn'>
): [() => void, UseQueryResult<unknown, unknown>] {
  const [enabled, setEnabled] = useState(false);

  const query = useQuery<TData, TError, unknown, QueryKey>(key, fetchFn, {
    ...(options || {}),
    enabled,
  });

  const trigger = useCallback(() => {
    if (!enabled) {
      setEnabled(true);
    }
  }, [fetchFn, enabled]);

  return [trigger, query];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this

```
const { isLoading, data } = useQuery([
    'homePageSearchQuery',
    {recipeName}],
    () => searchRecipeByName(recipeName), {}
);
```

It will run the query whenever the value of recipeName changes.

Comment: Hi Ibrahim, I tried that initially, but it isn't working. I also tried calling the refetch function in my "handleOnSearchSubmit" function. But refetch doesn't take in the query string param

Comment: Ok, removing the enable does work. But that seems to fire the query on every rerender as well

Comment: Glad that it is working, since you initially had set enabled value to false, it was stopping the hook from firing the fetch query. About re-render you need to check what is causing multiple re-render and take care of it.

Comment: If you are using it for search, I will also suggest you to use `debounce` when using the query. I personally use `debounce` function from `lodash`

Comment: Thanks for that, it is used for search, but it's doing a search on a button click. But is there no way of only running the query only when the "handleOnSearchSubmit" is called? In Apollo client, there is the useLazyQuery hook natively.

Comment: You absolutely can. How about you control it using `enabled` prop. Define `[enabled, setEnabled] = useStat(false)` we set the initial value to false 
 so the query is not running on load. And in the `handleOnSearchSubmit` change the `enabled` value  to true.

Comment: I see, it's a shame React-query doesn't provide a useLazyQuery out of the box. Thanks for your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Lazy query can be implemented the following way:

```
import { useQueryClient } from '@tanstack/react-query';

export const useGetRecipeByNameLazy = () => {
  const queryClient = useQueryClient();
  return (recipeName: string) => queryClient.ensureQueryData({
    queryKey: ['homePageSearchQuery', recipeName],
    queryFn: () => searchRecipeByName(recipeName),
  });
};
```

The usage:

```
const getRecipeByName = useGetRecipeByNameLazy();

const handleSearch = async (recipeName: string) => {
    const recipe = await getRecipeByName(recipeName);
    console.log(recipe);
}
```