# how to make reusable react query hooks?

Tags: reactjs, react-query, state-management

I'm new to ReactQuery.

Usually, I wrote each use query on all pages, but I want to use it in several places as one.

I'm trying to write it down in hooks folder and export to use it, but it doesn't work

```
    // dataHook.js
    import axios from 'axios'
    import { useQuery } from 'react-query'


     const fetchCompanyInfo = async()=>{
        return await axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/')
      
     }

     export const useCompanyInfo = ()=>{
        return useQuery('companyInfo',()=>fetchCompanyInfo)
     }
```

```
    // page.js
    import { useCompanyInfo } from '../hooks/useCompanyInfo'

    const { data: companyInfo } = useCompanyInfo
```

My Question is: How to make react-query as we do in redux slice, separate from every single pages.js

Comment: It is not at all clear what you're asking here.. Can you clarify?

Comment: You have to call your query function `()=>fetchCompanyInfo()` or use the shorthand `fetchCompanyInfo`.

Answer (score -4):

To create a custom hook that holds multiple queries I would:

1. Create a new context using useContext:

   ```
   export const CustomQueriesContext = React.createContext();
   export const useCustomQueries = () => useContext(CustomQueriesContext);
   ```
2. Create a provider with the functions:

   ```
   export const CustomQueriesProvider = ({
       children
   }) => {
   const queryFunction = () => { 
   }

   return <CustomQueriesContext.Provider value={{
       exportedQuery: queryFunction
   }}>
        {children}
   </CustomQueriesContext.Provider>
   }
   ```
3. Wrap your app in the CustomQueriesProvider:

   ```
   <CustomQueriesProvider>
      <App/>
   </CustomQueriesProvider>
   ```
4. Now you can import useCustomQueries to any react component you like and call the query like this:

   ```
   const customQueries = useCustomQueries();
   let data = await customQueries.exportedQuery();
   ```

Comment: This doesn't even use react-query, or react-query like idioms 
(e.g. you don't await the data in the component)

Comment: I used this approach for calling the same GraphQL queries/mutations in multiple components. It will work for react-query as well. You just have to make the queries depend on a state variable for it to refetch the data when the function is called. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70515600/how-to-use-lazy-query-with-react-query